# How grunt uglify plugin works?

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs

I have a simple question: how does uglify work? Does it run, and write uglified code straight into the target directory, or does it create a temporary file and then replace target with the prepared file when task is over?

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual at: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify

the examples pretty much speak for themselves. You can tell Uglify where to write it.

```
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    my_target: {
      files: {
        'dest/output.min.js': ['src/input1.js', 'src/input2.js']
      }
    }
  }
});
```